# CentOS 6.9 mirrorlist problem can't find mirrorlist

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I have problem with mirrorlist on CentOS 6.9.
I tried use `baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/6.9/os/x86_64/` in `/etc/yum.repos.d`, but the are almost nothing, even no vim. Then I tried use `mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=i386&repo=os&infra=stock`, but suddenly the link isn't active. Then I tried use this link, but with release equals 7, but `yum` tried to reinstall whole the system since conflict between versions.

Can you provide me yum configuration for CentOS 6.9 i386.

Here the last configuration:

```
[centos-old.repo]
name=centos-old
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=i386&repo=os&infra=stock
#baseurl=https://vault.centos.org/6.9/os/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Helpful info:

```
[root@host  yum.repos.d]# cat /etc/*release
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-ia32:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
[root@host  yum.repos.d]# uname -p
i686
[root@host  yum.repos.d]#
```

Comment: CentOS 6 reached End Of Life almost two years ago, in November 2020. It really is time to upgrade to a newer version